# Why am I getting Error showing No such Directories in Terminal while executing a C program?

Tags: c, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently install windows subsystem linux
when I try to execute the C program it says no directory exists[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PTMiurg

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc one.c -one
```

Does not do what you want, if you want `one` to be name of output file use `-o` option as below.

```
 gcc one.c -o one
```

Then,

```
./one
```

will work

---

By default name of the executable generated is

```
./a.out
```